# Showing Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing a math website where I want to make a feature of calculating LCM(Largest Common Multiple) of some numbers. Here is my HTML code and respective Javascript code.

**HTML Code**

```html
<h1>LCM of Multiple Numbers</h1>
      <textarea id="lcmbox" rows="2" cols="100" placeholder="Enter multiple numbers separated by spaces"></textarea> <br>
      <button id="lcmbtn" onclick="lcmAll()">Calculate LCM</button> <br>
      <label id="lcmN"></label> <br>
      <label id="lcmAllRes"></label> <hr>
```

**Javascript Code**

```js
function gcd(a, b) {
    if (b == 0)
        return a;
    else
        return gcd (b,a%b);
}

function lcmAll() {
    var x = document.getElementById("lcmbox").value;
    var arr = x.split(" ");
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
      arr[i] = parseInt(arr[i]);
    var l = arr[0];
    var g;
    for (var i=1; i<arr.length; i++)
    {
      var g = gcd(l,arr[i]);
      l = (l / g) * arr[i];
    }
    document.getElementById("lcmN").innerHTML = "Total Numbers : "+arr.length;
    document.getElementById("lcmAllRes").innerHTML = "Calculated LCM : "+l;
}
```

The problem is, I get the correct output after testing it on a local browser. But after uploading it on the server, I get the following error,

> Uncaught ReferenceError: lcmAll is not defined
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

What is the problem here?

Comment: Is the function definition in the global scope?

Comment: Actually I have another javascript file in which I wrote the code. I just linked the source of that js file in the html file with <script> tag.

Comment: But is the function defined at the global scope, or is it nested inside another function?

Comment: Such as inside `window.onload = function() { ... }`

Comment: No, it is not nested.

Comment: Are you sure the script is being loaded? Do you see it in the Sources tab of Developer Tools?

Comment: Well, it loads and gives the correct result when tested offline. But after uploading in the server, it gives error. I checked the error on the **Console** tab under **Inspect Element** feature of the browser.

Comment: @Barmar Here one thing, I can't see the the code in the sources tab. :(

Comment: Then there must be a problem with the `<script src="..."></script>` tag, it's not loading the file.

Comment: But there are some other functions in that script and they runs good as well.

Comment: If the file isn't listed in Sources, it didn't load. I don't know how other functions could be working.

Comment: If you have a syntax error in a file, it will define everything before that, everything after it will fail.

Comment: I would highly advise you don't slack on proper usage of braces. It would make diagnosing issues like this far easier. I recommend perhaps pasting your code into codepen/jsfiddle ans seeing if it still works. If so, then you know its a server issue; if not, then you know its an issue with your code.

Comment: @Pytth Yes, it works on codepen. But I still can't see the function in the sources tab! :(

Comment: If some functions from the script file exist and some don't, you're probably loading an older version of it from cache. Clear your browser cache and try again.